# One svg has width crushed to 0 if sibling is rendered via img element with no set width

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I discovered a very interesting bug today, which requires very precise set of circumstances.

I work for a SaaS company, and work on a React frontend with a modular UI that we re-brand for each customer.

The TSX for where I discovered this issue looks like this (trigger warning: Tailwind):

```js
<div className="flex items-center gap-2">
  {customerLogo?.source ? (
    <img className="object-contain" src={customerLogo.source} />
  ) : null}
  <span>powered by</span>
  <MyCompanySVG />
</div>
```

```js
export default function MyCompanySVG () {
  return (
    <svg
      width="101px"
      height="24px"
    >
      ...
    </svg>
  );
}
```

This has worked for a myriad of customer images to date, including all different file types - SVGs, PNGs, BMPs, etc. However, when a customer asked us to update their logo to a newer one, it broke - the customer's logo showed up, but ours did not. On further inspection, our logo was still rendered, but its width had been reduced to 0, and no amount of manipulation of the SVG width properties on the logo itself would rectify the issue.

Troubleshooting was when things really got interesting. First, I tried copying & pasting the raw SVG from the customer image as TSX, doing a quick find-and-replace for translating `class` to `className` and `xmlns:xlink` to `xmlnsXlink`. I otherwise left it unchanged, and - it was fixed. I hadn't even really begun to investigate - simply rendering the customer's SVG outside of an img tag, un-broke my company's seemingly unrelated SVG.

After further experimentation, I determined that moving the customer image, still inside the img tag, outside of the same parent div, also un-broke our company logo. Only when rendered as sibling did it cause this behavior.

It was at this point I realized I should open the old & new SVG files side by side to determine what might have been different between them. After comparing some properties, I realized that the new SVG had no width or height  set, only a viewBox. I added a width property to the top-level of the customer SVG, and voila - the new SVG, rendered as an img source, no longer caused our company logo to collapse to 0 width. Adding this width to the img tag itself also fixes the problem.

You can imagine my confusion here - how does not setting a width on one SVG, cause a different sibling that ***does*** have a width set to collapse to 0, only when the SVG with unset width is rendered via an `img` tag? Even when setting the `img` tag or SVG width to ***the same width as it was rendering before the setting*** fixes the problem, so it's not that the new logo was simply too wide and somehow squishing the other; irrespective of its size, if the width is unset, later top-level SVGs have their width set to 0.

This behavior is observed in both Chrome and Firefox, so it seems to be some quirk of the CSS spec rather than an outright bug in Blink or Gecko (unless it's a bug in both).

My question is, what is the underlying CSS layout rule or rules that cause this behavior? I'd like to understand better so that I might recognize it in the future.

Comment: Do you use flexbox? (I see className ="flex...") If so the css would be relevant